# How to extract some <li> (under ol / ul tag) tags from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have html string (js string) as below

```
<ol class="testClass">
<li>test1</li>
<li>testing2</li>
<li>testing3</li>
<li>testing4</li>
<li>testing5</li>
<li>testing6</li>
</ol>
```

I need just 2 to 3 list items, and discard the rest (as below)

```
<ol class="testClass">
<li>test1</li>
<li>testing2</li>
<li>testing3</li>
</ol>
```

Any idea how to do this? can I use jQuery to return subset of ol? or is there a regex for this?

**Edit:**

Thanks a lot for your answers. I have a sub question (sorry I should have asked this with original question)

I want to limit just the li corresponding to test class (and not consider the li under testClass2 for removal).

```
<ol class="testClass">
<li>test1</li>
<li>testing2</li>
<li>testing3</li>
<ul class="testClass2">    
 <li>testing4</li>
<li>testing5</li>
</ul>
<li>testing6</li>

</ol>
```

I tried something like

```
html.not('.testClass2').find("li:gt(3)").remove();
```

but its still considering the inner elements

This seems to work:

```
html.find("ol>li:gt(4)").remove();
```

Comment: Just to be sure, do you have this HTML as a JS string with literal new-lines, or are they actual elements on a page?

Comment: When you say you need them, what exactly do you need to do with them? Are they going to be inserted into the DOM? Or do you need to extract some content from them?

Comment: I have a code that extracts just steps (ol /ul) from a html string. I use that data to display it as steps in UI. I don't want to display all the steps in the UI rather just top 3 or 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another jQuery way:

```
<div id="demo"></div>

var html = $('<ol class="testClass"><li>test1</li><li>testing2</li><li>testing3</li><li>testing4</li><li>testing5</li><li>testing6</li></ol>');
html.find("li:gt(2)").remove();
$("#demo").append(html);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply convert them to DOM elements, and use normal selectors.

It sounds like you want to append only the first 3 `li` elements, so just grab the children of the `ul`, and slice the first 3 before appending to the page.

```
$(my_string).children("li").slice(0, 3).appendTo("#target");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really have a string and want to use jQuery, then you can parse it, then find all elements with indices higher than 2 and remove them:

```
var $html = $('<ol class="testClass"><li>test1</li><li>testing2</li><li>testing3</li><li>testing4</li><li>testing5</li><li>testing6</li></ol>');

$html.find('li:gt(2)').remove();

$('<div>').append($html.clone()).html(); // This returns the new HTML code.

$('#wrapper').append($html); // This would append it to a #wrapper element.
```

Comment: You're actually creating the elements 3 times. Once is enough. And the line that starts with `$('<div>')` doesn't actually do anything at all. You're cloning the new elements, appending them to the new `div`, turning it into an HTML string, then throwing it all away. ;-)

Comment: You're right, the line does not anything at all, but I was unsure,  if he needs it as a string again and with that line he could do it. But your tip that the cloning is unnecessary is true anyway! But I still like your answer more, because your solution *takes 3* instead of *throwing the rest away*. :-)

Comment: It was hard to tell if he needed a string or not. If he does, then just drop the `.clone()` and save the `.html()` in a variable and you're good to go! :-)

Answer (score 0):

#### Without jQuery

```js
var str = '<ol class="testClass"><li>test1</li><li>testing2</li><li>testing3</li><li>testing4</li><li>testing5</li><li>testing6</li></ol>',
    // Maximum number of <li>s you want to keep
    max = 2,
    temp = document.createElement('div'),
    res = '';

// Put the string in a temporary DOM
temp.innerHTML = str;
// Find <li>s
var lis = temp.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i = 0, l=lis.length; i<l && i<max; i++){
    // Append them to a string
    res += lis[i].outerHTML;
}
// Empty the list and insert the ones you kept
temp.childNodes[0].innerHTML = res;

document.body.innerHTML = temp.innerHTML;
```

Comment: `i--; i++` is the same as `i`. ;-)

Comment: I don't think you deserved a `-1` so I offset it, plus it's nice to give a native solution. Side note, IMO you don't need to do all that HTML manipulation after the elements are made. You could actually just append the first 2 elements directly.

Comment: @LyeFish Thank you. Yes, I'm often embarrased when looking for a native solution and only find jQuery solutions. And you're right, I'll edit that. Thanks mate.

Comment: I totally agree. It can can be a bit much to sift through all the jQuery stuff to find a native solution here. I don't actually use jQuery anymore, so I've got all this now useless knowledge that I've got to do something with! ;-D

Comment: @LyeFish I quit using jQuery too when I started working on mobile web apps using large sets of data. It was wayyy too slow. Sure it's easier to maintain, but when file size and performance come in play, it's not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates Lye Fish's answer:

https://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/qbj50dms/

HTML:

```
<ol id="target">
</ol>
```

Javascript (with jQuery):

```
var str = "<ol class=\"testClass\">" + 
"<li>test1</li>" +
"<li>testing2</li>" +
"<li>testing3</li>" +
"<li>testing4</li>" +
"<li>testing5</li>" +
"<li>testing6</li>" +
"</ol>";

$(str).children("li").slice(0, 3).appendTo("#target");
```